# Web-based unit-testing in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

I have a bunch of C# unit tests on my teams Team Foundation Server. Normally we Run these tests using Jetbrains test-suite. However, I've like to make these tests available to the QA department, through a browser.

**Is there any way to easily make C# unit test runnable through the web?** Anybody who have experience with this?
I have googled it and i'm only able to find client applications to run unittests.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your Unit Test should be for developers and Continuos Integration process, QA departement should run UI/Web Coded/Performance Test by VS Test Manager; anyway if you configure the execution of the test suite in the build configuration, test result will be available also from TFS Web Access
[Run tests in your build process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138.aspx)